# How to send datagridview changed contents to stimulsoft report?

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, report, stimulsoft

I have a RadDataGridView control in my form which retrieve data from a table using LINQ. In one column, I read integer values as status and show a string instead of integer values like this. I summarize it:

```
         myDataClassesDataContext dtContext = new myDataClassesDataContext();
        var query = from m in dtContext.tbl1
                    select new
                    { 
                        m.class,
                        m.NAME,
                        m.FNAME, 
                        status=(
                            m.KODVAZ==1?"finished":
                            m.KODVAZ==2?"in progress":"unknown"
                        ),                            
                         m.id
                    };
        radGridView1.DataSource = query;
```

I send my DataGridView data to a StimulsoftReport like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523692/storing-filtered-rows-of-datagridview-in-a-datatable), but value of this column(status)is not displayed in my report. How can print these value?

Comment: Do you have such column in DataSet that you register?

Comment: @HighAley yes.As I said I send my datagridview content to stimulsoftreport.

Comment: It's impossible to send DataGridView to the report.It could be DataSet or DataTable. What code do you use to register your data?